# Edit table data cell using a edit icon shown over hover

Tags: jquery, html-table, cell, edit, tablerow

I have a grid with multiple cols & rows. I want edit just one cell at a time. By showing a edit icon when the user hovers the td, I want the user to be able to click the edit icon and then the td becomes editable. onblur will retain the new value and the edit icon is also hidden when the td is not in focus.

I am not able to write the code for this, I want to apply JQuery techniques.

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr id="r1">
    <td>- |</td>
    <td>blah 1 |</td>
    <td>blah 2 <div class="editit" style="background:url(pencil.png) no-repeat"></div></td>
  </tr>
```

It will be great if the JQuery experts help me solve this issue.

Comment: You're going to have to put more effort in. What have you tried? What works? What doesn't? Using jQuery is still writing code...

Comment: By now you have three possible answers, if you are disagree with all three please post your own or if you are agree so must lets us know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple but effective: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Trads/)

On hover it shows a span with text. You can make this a button or whatever you like. This span acts as edit and save button.

Comment: Thank you Rune, This works good, but I see that once I fill in new value and then blur out of the textbox it will retain the textbox, how can we also hide the textbox and retain the new value.

Comment: @JQueryNewbie use the `on("blur"..)` event. I have updated the fiddle with the blur event: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Trads/1/)

Comment: I have also similar type of problem, but in my case I have to show the data table from json data, which is done. The problem is there is a fields status which value is 1 or 0, and based on this value I have to show a cells value as check_icon and cross_icon. I am using foundation dataTable.js, I gone through complete jquery file and edited some section that I dont want but I could not understand, where I can check the field value in jquery.dataTable.min.js and assign respected icon.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td').click(function(){
    var theText = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" value="'+theText+'"/>');
    $(this).find('input').focus();
});
$('td').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({'background' : 'url(http://www.earthclaim.com/images/edit_icon.gif) no-repeat right'});
}, function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'none');
});
$(document).on('blur', 'input', function(){
    var theText = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().html(theText);    
});
```

​
[Working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2vUSP/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but the best way to solve that problem is to use a plugin to convert the entire table into a Grid with many options like cell's edition.
This is a list with 10 most used Grids for Jquery

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-grids/

Just visit one and see documentation or examples of usage, like this one:
http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Or this

http://flexigrid.info/